# Formula to compute 10 year US governement bond price given yield

Tags: bonds, calculation

What is the formula to convert US govy 10 year yields ([as those shown here](http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=%5Etnx&fr=uh3_finance_web&uhb=uhb2)) in to bond prices?

I know in general the math looks like [this](http://www.investopedia.com/university/advancedbond/advancedbond2.asp) but I don't know what the values of the variables are for a plain vanilla US 10 year govy paper (# of coupons, pay out at maturity ect)

Answer (score 2):

[Treasury Direct](http://www.treasurydirect.gov/instit/marketables/tbonds/tbonds.htm)  tells us:

- Treasury bonds are interest-bearing securities with maturities over 10 years.
- Treasury bonds pay interest on a semi-annual basis.
- When a bond matures, the investor receives the face value.

A 10 year US treasury bond has 20 coupons and pays face value at maturity.  Were there other variables you needed?

Comment: I can't vote (too low reps) but I have a further question: If r is the annual yield, to get the the semi-annual yield, do you just divide the annual yield in by (i.e. (1+r/2)) , or do you do sqrt((1+r)). The web site I linked to says the former, but the latter seems more logical (interests compound!)

Comment: @user42397 Bonds are quoted based on the periodic interest rate times the number of payments in a year, not the true "annualized" interest rate, so dividing the quoted rate by 2 is appropriate to find the periodic rate for a semi-annual bond.